# Execute copy command from postgre in function and create a file

Tags: function, unix, copy, greenplum

My requirement is like create a function to copy data from query to file and capture it's count. Example

```
  Create function xoy(query,path) returns integer as
   Copy (query) to stdout >path of file
    Get row_count of the query above
    Close
```

The above is a base logic needed ,please help
Postgre SQL 8.3,greenplum

Comment: It is faster to use an External Table with gpfdist to write that file.  Also, what are you going to do with the file once it is created?

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of using gpfdist and an external table.  This will provide the fastest performance to write an external file.  You should also be aware that you can write to S3, HDFS, and others with PXF.

This is a sample table in Greenplum:

```
create table foo
(id int,
 fname text,
 lname text,
 city text,
 state text,
 zip text)
distributed by (id);
```

Insert some dummy data for this example:

```
insert into foo 
(id, fname, lname, city, state, zip)
select i, 'foo_' || i, 'bar_' || i, 'city_' || i, 'state_' || i, 'zip_' || i
from generate_series(1, 10000) as i;
```

This is an writable external table that uses gpfdist.

```
create writable external table ext_foo
(like foo)
location ('gpfdist://mdw:8999/foo.txt')
format 'text' (delimiter '|' null as '')
distributed by (id);
```

Here is your function you wanted to use:

```
create or replace function fn_export_foo() returns void as
$$
declare

begin
    insert into ext_foo 
    select * from foo;
end

$$
language plpgsql;
```

And now, on the mdw host (as specified in the writable external table definition), start gpfdist from bash.

```
gpfdist -p 8999 > gpfdist_8999.log 2>&1 < gpfdist_8999.log &
```

And now execute the function:

```
select fn_export_foo();
```

Here are the results:

```
[gpadmin@mdw ~]$ head foo.txt 
42|foo_42|bar_42|city_42|state_42|zip_42
74|foo_74|bar_74|city_74|state_74|zip_74
90|foo_90|bar_90|city_90|state_90|zip_90
122|foo_122|bar_122|city_122|state_122|zip_122
234|foo_234|bar_234|city_234|state_234|zip_234
250|foo_250|bar_250|city_250|state_250|zip_250
293|foo_293|bar_293|city_293|state_293|zip_293
325|foo_325|bar_325|city_325|state_325|zip_325
341|foo_341|bar_341|city_341|state_341|zip_341
373|foo_373|bar_373|city_373|state_373|zip_373
```

In my test cluster, the file with 10,000 records was written in 143 ms.

Comment: the only thing is here at my side my query would change every time the file generates so I can't go with table

Comment: The example uses a table to provide sample data. It does not have to be a table, but can be a query. This query inserts into the external table - which is just a vehicle to write out the data.